# How to apply filter for one particular servlet using a servlet3.0?

Tags: servlets, annotations, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I'm using servlet 3.0 but i can't specify filter for only one servlet using annotations?
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found this and it is working with me

```
 @WebFilter(filterName = "BasicFilter" , urlPatterns = {"/BasicFilter"},servletNames ={"/FilteredServlet"})
```